Why DatePicker not working with onTapGesture in SwiftUI
while building my app i encountered an issue that when i embed a DatePicker inside VStack and implement a onTapGesture on VStack then the DatePicker won't open calendar to pick dates on click.
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if selectedOption == .dates {
                    Text("When's your trip?")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    VStack {
                        DatePicker("From", selection: $startDate ,displayedComponents: .date)
                        Divider()
                        DatePicker("To", selection: $endDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                }else {
                    CollapsedPickerView(title: "When", description: "Add Dates")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(height: selectedOption == .dates ? 180 : 64)
            .background(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    selectedOption = .dates
                }
            }

the code above does not work but if i remove the onTapGesture it works fine.
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if selectedOption == .dates {
                    Text("When's your trip?")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    VStack {
                        DatePicker("From", selection: $startDate ,displayedComponents: .date)
                        Divider()
                        DatePicker("To", selection: $endDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                }else {
                    CollapsedPickerView(title: "When", description: "Add Dates")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(height: selectedOption == .dates ? 180 : 64)
            .background(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 10)

although the first code works in and youtube video of building same functionality for a clone app.
full code:
//
//  DestinationSearchView.swift
//  Airbnb
//
//  Created by ADITYA RAJ on 30/06/24.
//

import SwiftUI

enum DestinationSearchOptions {
    case location
    case dates
    case guests
}

struct DestinationSearchView: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool
    @State private var destination = ""
    @State private var selectedOption: DestinationSearchOptions = .location
    @State private var startDate = Date()
    @State private var endDate = Date()
    @State private var numGuest = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    show.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if selectedOption == .location {
                    Text("Where to?")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            .imageScale(.small)
                        TextField("Search Destination", text: $destination)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    .frame(height: 44)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .overlay {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color(.systemGray4))
                    }
                }else {
                    CollapsedPickerView(title: "Where", description: "Add Destination")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(height: selectedOption == .location ? 120 : 64)
            .background(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    selectedOption = .location
                }
            }
            // date selection view
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if selectedOption == .dates {
                    Text("When's your trip?")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    VStack {
                        DatePicker("From", selection: $startDate ,displayedComponents: .date)
                        Divider()
                        DatePicker("To", selection: $endDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                }else {
                    CollapsedPickerView(title: "When", description: "Add Dates")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(height: selectedOption == .dates ? 180 : 64)
            .background(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    selectedOption = .dates
                }
            }
            // num guests view
            VStack {
                if selectedOption == .guests {
                    Text("Who's coming")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Stepper(
                        onIncrement: { 
                            numGuest += 1
                        },
                        onDecrement: { 
                            guard numGuest > 0 else {return}
                            numGuest -= 1
                        },
                        label: {
                            Text("\(numGuest) Adults")
                        })
                }else {
                    CollapsedPickerView(title: "Who", description: "Add Guests")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(height: selectedOption == .guests ? 120 : 64)
            .background(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    selectedOption = .guests
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    DestinationSearchView(show: .constant(false))
}



on clicking the datepicker it should open calendar dialog.

DatePicker doesn't need a tap gesture, it already has its own gesture. I'm not sure what is the purpose of done property, if you want to know when user selected a date, you could use onReceive modifier for your pickDate property.
struct Test: View {
    @State private var pickDate = Date()
    @State private var done = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("From", selection: $pickDate ,displayedComponents: .date)
        }
        .onChange(of: pickDate) { value in
            // Date has changed
        }
    }
}

If for some reason, you need to have a gesture recognizer work with Buttons/DatePickers, you can use simultaneousGesture.

Please understand the usage of DatePicker from this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-date-picker-and-read-values-from-it
You don't need to manually handle its tap gesture, it is by default implemented.
